# Check if value exist in MySQL failing

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

For God's sake, what is wrong with my code? I'm trying to check if value exists in MySQL through AJAX when some input lose its focus, but I always get the same response:

**SCRIPT:** lose its

```
  $(function() {
     $('#cnpj').focusout(function() {
        var a = $('#cnpj').val();
        if(verificar(a) === true){$('#cnpjerror').show();}
     });

     $('#email').focusout(function() {
        var b = $('#email').val();
        if(verificar(b) === true){$('#emailerror').show();}
     });
  })

  function verificar(x) {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'verify.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'check='+x+'&way=1',
        success: function(serverResponse) {
           alert('There is not');
           return false;
        },
        error: function(serverResponse) {
           alert('There is');
           return true;
        }
     });
  }
```

**VERIFY.PHP:**

```
   if(isset($_POST["check"]) && $_POST["way"]) == 1){

      $check = $_POST["check"];

      $sql = "SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Email = '$check' UNION SELECT ID FROM Table2 WHERE Email = '$check'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
         die;
      } else {

      }
```

Everytime I get "There is not", even if I write some value that exist. I already checked if the first function is sending the correct value and it is =(

Comment: First, remove the AJAX part since it's not related. You have to eliminate as much of the code as possible to be able to localize the bug. Then check what's inside the `$sql` variable right before the `mysqli_query` call, try to execute that query manually against the DB and check if it returns what you expect. You just need to do very simple debugging.

Comment: You're saying that you are always getting a success (There is not is in the success function) I do not see what your issue is?

Answer (score 0):

`success: function(serverResponse) {
           alert('There is not');
           return false;
        },`

Notice that in success you put `alert('there is not');`. So what is wrong? Your response runs well.

Comment: Even if I put a value that "There is" in my Table, I get "There is not". There is no way to me to get the other alert.

Comment: @Igor that is correct. You should try alert(serverResponse). Also note that your php file does not echo/return anything so this will most likely be empty.

Comment: Thank you, @nerdlyist, there was something wrong with my code =)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified you script little bit. Explanation : As ajax is asynchronous call since whatever script you want to execute that need to return in success or error function itself.

```
 $(function() {
     $('#cnpj').focusout(function() {
        var a = $('#cnpj').val();
        verificar(a, "cnjp")
     });

     $('#email').focusout(function() {
        var b = $('#email').val();
        verificar(b, "email"); 

     });
  })

  function verificar(x, reference) {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'verify.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'check='+x+'&way=1',
        success: function(serverResponse) {


        },
        error: function(serverResponse) {
            if(reference== "cnjp") {
               $('#cnpjerror').show();
               } 
               if(reference== "email") {
               $('#emailerror').show();
               } 
        }
     });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I found the problem =)

Comment: can you specify your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nerdlyist, I pus `serverResponse` in an `alert()` and I found this:

```
if(isset($_POST["check"]) && $_POST["way"]) == 1){
```

There was an extra parentesis here: `$_POST["way"])`.

The correct would be:

```
if(isset($_POST["check"]) && $_POST["way"] == 1){
```

Thank you all!